# Stopping the execution of a currently running job after some time

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule jobs to be executed daily as a part of a much larger web application. However, after a couple of days, the administrator would like to stop the execution of a particular job (maybe because it is no longer needed). How do I go about doing this? I read the api docs for the Scheduler and it has a method called interrupt(JobKey jobkey) but that method would work only with the same instance of the scheduler that was used to schedule the job.

> interrupt(JobKey jobKey)
>
> Request the interruption, within this Scheduler instance, of all
> currently executing instances of the identified Job, which must be an
> implementor of the InterruptableJob interface.

Is there anyway of getting the instance of an existing scheduler? Or maybe use singletons?

Answer (score 0):

Should definitely use a singleton instance of your scheduler. I recommend the use of an IoC container to manage this in a clean and efficient way.

Comment: Usually, a scheduler is an instance obtained from the scheduler factory. How do I get a singleton of the scheduler itself?

Comment: You could either store your instance in a static variable or use an IoC container to retrieve your instance.